# Issue with getHibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate

Tags: hibernate

Hi I am using Hibernate 3.0

Facing some issue with data saving.

in below code client is pojo that i want to save. Even though i tried to flush still same problem

```
try {
            getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(client);
            System.out.println("This is executed");
            getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush();
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Getting Following Exception

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:574)
    at com.hewitt.appinv.dao.ClientDAOImpl.saveClient(ClientDAOImpl.java:118)
```

Comment: Give us more details (about your transactions and session flush mode at least)

Comment: As Bozho said we need more info on this to figure out what the problem is but you could try:   getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush()

Comment: HibernateTemplate?  Are you using Spring?  If so you should upgrade to the latest and they do not recommend using HibernateTemplate anymore.  You should use the OpenSessionInView filter with the HibernateTransactionManager where you can just call sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() to return a Hibernate Session object. Then you can just use the hibernate api.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
hibernate.current_session_context_class = thread
```

For the session and also use this

```
hibernate property<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
    ${hibernate.current_session_context_class}
/prop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have some experience in nhibernate, not uin hibernate, but perhaps you should flush.